How to expand/contract a SliverAppBar shared via ShellRoute with GoRoutes?
This is a follow-up question. Here is the original: How to use CustomScrollView in a GoRouter ShellRoute?
I am trying to generate a CustomScrollView with a collapsible SliverAppBar at the top. Beneath the SliverAppBar will be the content from the various page routes. To get the routing working, I had to create a nested CustomScrollView within the parent, because GoRoute#builder can't return a Sliver directly; it must return a Widget.
Here's what I have so far:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:go_router/go_router.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const App());
}

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  const App({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var title = 'Flutter Demo';
    return MaterialApp.router(
        title: title,
        theme: ThemeData(
          colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
          useMaterial3: true,
        ),
        routerConfig:
            GoRouter(navigatorKey: GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(), routes: [
          ShellRoute(
              navigatorKey: GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(),
              builder:
                  (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state, Widget child) {
                return ShellRouteWidget(child: child);
              },
              routes: [
                GoRoute(
                    path: "/",
                    builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
                      return const RouteWidget();
                    })
              ])
        ]));
  }
}

class ShellRouteWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  ShellRouteWidget({super.key, required this.child});

  final Widget child;
  final ScrollController scrollController = ScrollController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scrollbar(
      controller: scrollController,
      child: CustomScrollView(controller: scrollController, slivers: [
        SliverAppBar(
          pinned: true,
          expandedHeight: 300.0,
          flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
            background: Container(
              color: Colors.red,
              child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                      style: Theme.of(context).primaryTextTheme.displayLarge,
                      "Should Expand/Contract when scrolling")),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        SliverToBoxAdapter(child: SizedBox(height: 500, child: child))
      ]),
    );
  }
}

class RouteWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const RouteWidget({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CustomScrollView(
      controller: context
          .findAncestorWidgetOfExactType<ShellRouteWidget>()!
          .scrollController,
      slivers: [
        SliverList(
            delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(List.generate(
                50,
                (index) => index % 2 == 0
                    ? Container(color: Colors.blue, child: const Text("even"))
                    : Container(
                        color: Colors.green, child: const Text("odd"))))),
      ],
    );
  }
}

But I need to get creative with the scroll controllers... When I scroll down through the content of the GoRoute, the SliverAppBar in the ShellRoute should collapse. I cannot simply share one scrollController between the two CustomScrollViews because I get this error:
======== Exception caught by animation library =====================================================
The following assertion was thrown while notifying status listeners for AnimationController:
The provided ScrollController is currently attached to more than one ScrollPosition.

The Scrollbar requires a single ScrollPosition in order to be painted.

When the scrollbar is interactive, the associated ScrollController must only have one ScrollPosition attached.The provided ScrollController must be unique to one ScrollView widget.

